# React-Native: How to add full screen Lottie animation

Tags: react-native, lottie

I am using linear gradient from lottie, the code is working fine with ios but in android its not fitting to full screen, there is some kind of padding between gradient and the view.
On ios its working fine...i tried many ways,
buy including `padding` to 0 and even margin to -20, but nothing worked...any solution?
[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Platform,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
import SignInScreen from './src/screens/auth/SignInScreen';
import Animation from 'lottie-react-native';

 import anim from './assets/gradient_animated_background.json';
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height + 20;
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width + 20;

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.animation.play();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Animation
            ref={animation => {
              this.animation = animation;
            }}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'red',
              height: '100%',
              width: '100%'
            }}
            loop={true}
            source={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? anim : 'gradient_animated_background.json'}
          />
       </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    flex: 1,
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: '#ffffff'
  }
});
```

The animation, and when ever i keep changing the width and height..it forcefully tries to maintain the aspect radio...(not sure though)

```
{"v":"4.6.10","fr":15,"ip":0,"op":155,"w":1080,"h":1920,"nm":"background","ddd":0,"assets":[],"layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":4,"nm":"Shape Layer 1","ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":{"a":0,"k":0},"p":{"a":0,"k":[540,960,0]},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100]}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ty":"rc","d":1,"s":{"a":0,"k":[1160,880]},"p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0]},"r":{"a":0,"k":0},"nm":"Rectangle Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Rect"},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.9960784,0.7843137,0.145098,1]},"o":{"a":0,"k":100},"w":{"a":0,"k":6},"lc":1,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke"},{"ty":"gf","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":1,"g":{"p":3,"k":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":0,"s":[0,0.511,0.89,0.283,0.5,0.334,0.873,0.583,1,0.156,0.857,0.882],"e":[0,0.726,0.283,0.89,0.5,0.441,0.356,0.886,1,0.156,0.429,0.882]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":31,"s":[0,0.726,0.283,0.89,0.5,0.441,0.356,0.886,1,0.156,0.429,0.882],"e":[0,0.89,0.283,0.283,0.5,0.886,0.553,0.219,1,0.882,0.823,0.156]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":61,"s":[0,0.89,0.283,0.283,0.5,0.886,0.553,0.219,1,0.882,0.823,0.156],"e":[0,0,0.312,0.737,0.5,0.078,0.597,0.754,1,0.156,0.882,0.771]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":91,"s":[0,0,0.312,0.737,0.5,0.078,0.597,0.754,1,0.156,0.882,0.771],"e":[0,0.51,0.89,0.282,0.5,0.333,0.873,0.582,1,0.157,0.855,0.882]},{"t":120}]}},"s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":0,"s":[-430.769,-404.573],"e":[23.726,-364.48],"to":[75.7491683959961,6.68213844299316],"ti":[-123.915840148926,-8.51547145843506]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":31,"s":[23.726,-364.48],"e":[312.726,-353.48],"to":[123.915840148926,8.51547145843506],"ti":[-1.00208830833435,-1.83333337306976]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":61,"s":[312.726,-353.48],"e":[29.739,-353.48],"to":[1.00208830833435,1.83333337306976],"ti":[120.055290222168,0.60746711492538]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":91,"s":[29.739,-353.48],"e":[-407.606,-357.125],"to":[-120.055290222168,-0.60746711492538],"ti":[72.8907089233398,0.60746711492538]},{"t":120}]},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":0,"s":[374.412,342.611],"e":[22.822,357.191],"to":[-58.5984153747559,2.42986845970154],"ti":[132.520950317383,-7.89707231521606]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":31,"s":[22.822,357.191],"e":[-420.714,389.994],"to":[-132.520950317383,7.89707231521606],"ti":[-4.68509674072266,-7.89707231521606]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":61,"s":[-420.714,389.994],"e":[50.932,404.573],"to":[4.68509674072266,7.89707231521606],"ti":[-132.918350219727,4.25226974487305]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":91,"s":[50.932,404.573],"e":[376.797,364.48],"to":[132.918350219727,-4.25226974487305],"ti":[-54.3107261657715,6.68213844299316]},{"t":120}]},"t":1,"nm":"Gradient Fill 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - G-Fill"},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[93.29,219.491],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Rectangle 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group"}],"ip":0,"op":155,"st":0,"bm":0,"sr":1},{"ddd":0,"ind":2,"ty":1,"nm":"Deep Red Solid 1","ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":{"a":0,"k":0},"p":{"a":0,"k":[540,960,0]},"a":{"a":0,"k":[540,960,0]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100]}},"ao":0,"sw":1080,"sh":1920,"sc":"#be2a2a","ip":0,"op":155,"st":0,"bm":0,"sr":1}]}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the animation as well?

Comment: @ovidb updated my question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are missing is the `resizeMode`, which is not specified on the documentation page, but if you look at the source you'll find it.

Here's something that works if you don't care to lose a few pixels:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';
import { anim } from './assets/animation.json';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window')

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.animation.play();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <LottieView
            ref={animation => {
              this.animation = animation;
            }}
            style={{
              width: width + 10,
              height: height,
              marginLeft: - 5
            }}
            resizeMode='cover'
            loop={true}
            source={anim}
          />
       </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Notice that I've exported the asset a bit differently since I tried this on https://snack.expo.io and for some reason they don't like JSON files , so now the assets look something

`/assets/animation.json.js`

```
export const anim = {"v":"4.6.10","fr":15,"ip":0,"op":155,"w":1080,"h":1920,"nm":"background","ddd":0,"assets":[],"layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":4,"nm":"Shape Layer 1","ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":{"a":0,"k":0},"p":{"a":0,"k":[540,960,0]},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100]}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ty":"rc","d":1,"s":{"a":0,"k":[1160,880]},"p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0]},"r":{"a":0,"k":0},"nm":"Rectangle Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Rect"},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.9960784,0.7843137,0.145098,1]},"o":{"a":0,"k":100},"w":{"a":0,"k":6},"lc":1,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke"},{"ty":"gf","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":1,"g":{"p":3,"k":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":0,"s":[0,0.511,0.89,0.283,0.5,0.334,0.873,0.583,1,0.156,0.857,0.882],"e":[0,0.726,0.283,0.89,0.5,0.441,0.356,0.886,1,0.156,0.429,0.882]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":31,"s":[0,0.726,0.283,0.89,0.5,0.441,0.356,0.886,1,0.156,0.429,0.882],"e":[0,0.89,0.283,0.283,0.5,0.886,0.553,0.219,1,0.882,0.823,0.156]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":61,"s":[0,0.89,0.283,0.283,0.5,0.886,0.553,0.219,1,0.882,0.823,0.156],"e":[0,0,0.312,0.737,0.5,0.078,0.597,0.754,1,0.156,0.882,0.771]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":91,"s":[0,0,0.312,0.737,0.5,0.078,0.597,0.754,1,0.156,0.882,0.771],"e":[0,0.51,0.89,0.282,0.5,0.333,0.873,0.582,1,0.157,0.855,0.882]},{"t":120}]}},"s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":0,"s":[-430.769,-404.573],"e":[23.726,-364.48],"to":[75.7491683959961,6.68213844299316],"ti":[-123.915840148926,-8.51547145843506]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":31,"s":[23.726,-364.48],"e":[312.726,-353.48],"to":[123.915840148926,8.51547145843506],"ti":[-1.00208830833435,-1.83333337306976]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":61,"s":[312.726,-353.48],"e":[29.739,-353.48],"to":[1.00208830833435,1.83333337306976],"ti":[120.055290222168,0.60746711492538]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":91,"s":[29.739,-353.48],"e":[-407.606,-357.125],"to":[-120.055290222168,-0.60746711492538],"ti":[72.8907089233398,0.60746711492538]},{"t":120}]},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":0,"s":[374.412,342.611],"e":[22.822,357.191],"to":[-58.5984153747559,2.42986845970154],"ti":[132.520950317383,-7.89707231521606]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":31,"s":[22.822,357.191],"e":[-420.714,389.994],"to":[-132.520950317383,7.89707231521606],"ti":[-4.68509674072266,-7.89707231521606]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":61,"s":[-420.714,389.994],"e":[50.932,404.573],"to":[4.68509674072266,7.89707231521606],"ti":[-132.918350219727,4.25226974487305]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":91,"s":[50.932,404.573],"e":[376.797,364.48],"to":[132.918350219727,-4.25226974487305],"ti":[-54.3107261657715,6.68213844299316]},{"t":120}]},"t":1,"nm":"Gradient Fill 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - G-Fill"},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[93.29,219.491],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Rectangle 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group"}],"ip":0,"op":155,"st":0,"bm":0,"sr":1},{"ddd":0,"ind":2,"ty":1,"nm":"Deep Red Solid 1","ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":{"a":0,"k":0},"p":{"a":0,"k":[540,960,0]},"a":{"a":0,"k":[540,960,0]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100]}},"ao":0,"sw":1080,"sh":1920,"sc":"#be2a2a","ip":0,"op":155,"st":0,"bm":0,"sr":1}]}
```

Comment: i am getting blue screen by copying your code...maybe this is has some different behaviour when using expo and cli...in your case you are using expo

Comment: Have you created the `/assets/animation.json.js` file pasted the code as I put at the end of my answer? Also tested on android device, and I had the problem you mentioned

Comment: Here is a working example, maybe you want to play a bit with the margins, I've noticed some weird border. https://snack.expo.io/@ovidb/lottie-fullscreen

Comment: ResizeMode works to me, which is not specified on the documentation page

Answer (score 4):

So the first answer raised an important point (adding resizeMode="cover").

But that's not enough, If you test across several screens sizes, you might still find unwanted margins and spaces. I had this issue too,

Here's the simple solution:

1. Get the dimensions of the lottie file (e.g 300 X 600)
2. Set `width` only, then use `aspectRatio` to determine the height. **(must)**
3. Set `flexGrow = 1` **(must)**

e.g

```html
<LottieView 
  style={{
      width: 300, 
      aspectRatio: 300 / 600,
      flexGrow: 1, 
      alignSelf: 'center',
    }} 
  resizeMode="cover" 
  ref={animation=> { this.animation = animation; }} 
  source={require ('./assets/animation.json')} 
  autoPlay={false} 
  loop={false} 
 />
```

I guess the problem arises because you cant use `width` and `height` at the same time in the styling of the Lottie view.

So an easy workaround is to use the `width` and `aspectRatio`

Good luck!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to use `resizeMode="cover"` according to first answer.

After that you have to use screen dimensions with `flexgrow: 1` property.

I tried through `aspect-ratio` but its not a solution for all the devices. I am sharing the example below like how you can make your `lottie animation` for every screen.

**Example Code**

```js
    import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { View } from "react-native";
    import { Dimensions, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
    import AnimatedLottieView from "lottie-react-native";
    
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
    
    const SplashScreen: FC = ({ navigation }: any) => {

    return (
    
    <View style={styles.lottieAnimationContainer}>
           
            <AnimatedLottieView 
            source={Animation.myy_loader} 
            style={styles.lottieAnimation} 
            autoPlay 
            loop={false} 
            resizeMode='cover'
            onAnimationFinish={async() => {
              setLottie(false);
          }} 
          />
    </View>
    )
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    lottieAnimationContainer: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent', // Transparent background
    zIndex: 1, // Ensure it's on top
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    },
    lottieAnimation: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: width, // Adjust width and height as needed
    height: height,
    },
    })
```

I hope this will be helpful for you.